# String indexing

Tags: string, indexing, python-3.5

Python 3.5

Here is my Code:

```
str1 = input("Please enter a full sentence: ").lower()
print("Thank you, You entered:" , str1)

str2 = input("Now please enter a word included in your sentence in anyway you like: ").lower()

if str2 in str1:
    print("That word was found!")
else:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```

As it is, it will search for the inputted word (str2) and if it is found in the input (str1 (a sentence)) it will say "the word has been found"). If the word is not in the sentence it will say "the word was not found".

I want to develop this so when the word is searched for and found, it tells the user the index position of the word (str2) in the sentence (str1). So for example: if I have the sentence ("I like to code in Python") and I search for the word ("code") the program should say "that word was found in index position: 4".

Btw the way, the code is not case sensitive as it converts all the words into lowercase with .lower.

If anyone could give me some advice on this then that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your `if ... else` by this:

```
try:
    print("That word was found at index %i!"% (str1.split().index(str2) + 1))
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Nice and simple with little change to the original code, the kind of thing i wanted. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("That word was found at index %i!"% (str1.split().index(str2)))
```

This will print the index of the first occurrence of str2 in str1.
The full code is:

```
str1 = input("Please enter a full sentence: ").lower()
print("Thank you, You entered:" , str1)

str2 = input("Now please enter a word included in your sentence in anyway you like: ").lower()

if str2 in str1:
    print("That word was found!")
    print("that word was found in index position: %i!"% (str1.split().index(str2)))
```

, str1.index(str2))
    else:
        print("Sorry, that word was not found")

Comment: Not exactly. `str1.split().index(str2)`

Comment: yep, invalid syntax

Comment: Hmmm.... I am not getting syntax errors.... Did you enter your input surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: I'm sorry @LukeP_8, my answer assumed you were using Python 2.7! You may want to add that as a tag.

Comment: Do you have another similar answer that could work in Python 3.5?

Comment: Yes, @LukeP_8. I edited the above code to work with Python 3.5.

Comment: thank you! this works for me, although it gives me completely the wrong index number. For example; if I type "I like to code in Python" as str1. Then I have "code" as str2, it gives me 10 as the index number when it should give me 3 as it is the 4th word in the string?

Comment: Last edit per @MosesKoledoye. This should be exactly what you want!

Answer (score 0):

```
str2 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
str1 = 'z'
index = str2.find(str1)
if index != -1:
    print 'That word was found in index position:',index
else:
    print 'That word was not found'
```

This will print the index of the str1 in str2

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable `str`, and you can `from string import ascii_lowercase` to get the alphabet

Comment: You're right, but he is clearly new to python and I don't want to confuse him with that import.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for me. But for some reason, it doesn't give me the correct index number. For example, if I gave "I like to code in Python" for str1, and then I searched for "code", it tells me it is in index position 10? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That's correct actually. Start counting from 0 and the word 'code' starts at index 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split() method: it's called on a string values and returns a list of strings. then you use index() method to find the index of the string.

```py
str1 = input("Please enter a full sentence: ").lower()
print("Thank you, You entered:" , str1)
str2 = input("Now please enter a word included in your sentence in anyway you like: ").lower()

if str2 in str1:
    a = str1.split() # you create a list
    # printing the word and index a.index(str2)
    print('The ', str2,' was find a the index ', a.index(str2)) 
    print("That word was found!")
else:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```